# Map domain with another domain url from dns

Tags: dns, cname

How can I configure DNS CNAME or another record which do the following requirement?

existing domain with its URL: example.com/brand/main/top
another domain: newdomain.com

My need is when I hit newdomain.com, it opens the existing domain URL (example.com/brand/main/top) with newdomain.com.

Comment: DNS only translates between hostnames and IP addresses, it can't handle URLs. This needs to be configured in your webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In CNAME, 
you can only point one domain to another domain.
path or url can't be mentioned in dns records.

to reach the url, you can configure htaccess to redirect incoming request of 
`newdomain.com` to `example.com/brand/main/top`

Comment: Thanks @GaneshKumar, in this case URL will be change or not?

Comment: yes. as per the redirection u mention in htaccess, url will change in browser.

if user enters url like newdomain.com, then redirection will happen and the url in browser will change to example.com/brand/main/top

Comment: `RewriteEngine on`  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$`  
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /brand/main/top/$1 [L]  `  
  
this above htaccess rule can be used for url redirection

Comment: for domain redirection, setup cname record for `newdomain.com` to point `example.com`